# What time of virtual machine when using VMotion from host to another host?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, time-synchronization, vmotion

Nomarlly, virtual machine get time from host, but when vsphere using VMotion to change virtual machine to new host. What's time of virtual machine when it in new host ? Old host time ? new host time ? or time sync from another source ? .

Answer (score 4):

When the migration is complete, assuming vmware tools is installed in the guest and is synchronizing the time, the time will be synchronized with the new server.

You should be using NTP to keep all your host clocks in sync, especially if you are using vmotion, so that this doesn't matter.